# Communication between discord.py function and non-discord.py function

Tags: discord.py

Let's say i have a class which requires a callback function (to debug):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback
        self.say_hello()
        self.say_goodbye()
    
    def say_hello(self):
        self.callback("hello")

    def say_goodbye(self):
        self.callback("goodbye")
```

The callback function (which is a discord.py function):

```
async def debug(ctx, msg):
    await ctx.send(msg)
```

There're 2 problems with the callback function above:

1. `MyClass` does not expect to pass `ctx` to the callback function
2. discord.py function can just be `command` or `event type`

Then how do I pass a discord.py function as a callback function to non-discord.py function as the example above? Thanks

Comment: You have to pass it the arguments it needs somehow, otherwise it doesn't know what channel to send it to (`ctx.send` -> `ctx.channel.send`). Also you're trying to call an async function in a non-async context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I provided in my answer definitely doesn't work, instead, I define `debug()` inside an async function and pass it to `callback` of `MyClass`:

```
@client.command()
async def abcd(ctx):
    def debug(msg):
        nonlocal ctx        
        await ctx.send(msg)
    # now init my class
    mc = MyClass()
    # let my class do whatever
```

Also remember to run the callback function with `asyncio`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explanation, where the self.callback in `MyClass` is the debug function, your `say_goodbye()` and `say_hello()` functions are missing certain values.

You can try to get the ctx by using a discord.py built in event:

```py
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send('your message')
```

in the `on_message()` event function, you can call functions that do what you want. Since it is an async method, you'd best be off writing async methods and calling them using await {function} in the on_message method.

```py
async def debug(ctx, msg):
    await ctx.send(msg)

myclass = MyClass(debug)


@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    content = ctx.content
    channel = ctx.channel
    # you can also call your debug function in your other functions
    await myclass.say_hello(ctx) 
    await myclass.say_goodbye(ctx)


    if content.startswith('whatever'):
        await do_whatever(ctx)
```

Although, the only downside to this is that your discord commands won't work, but that can be easily solved by manually adding each method check to your on_message function.

Anyways, hope this helped! :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, please consider an upvote for my question if you feel useful

Comment: ``on_message`` gets a Message, not a Context instance.

Comment: The point of this setup is to chang the way the code accesses discord messages so that the ctx instance can be passed through to the debugger. The first code snippet does exactly that. It uses the @bot.event decorator for the default `on_message` function which is redefined. The first snippet is just a sample of setting up the `on_message` function so that the second snippet would be easier to understand.